Webpack dev server includes runtime modules into entry bundle
I have very simple webpack configuration for one Typescript file as the entry (partial config) ...
config.entry = {
    launchEventsJS: {
      import: "./src/taskpane/launchEventsJS.ts",
      filename: getScriptName(dev),
    },
  };

And webpack-dev-server configuration as follow ...
const getDevServerConfig = async (): Promise<webpackDevServer.Configuration> => {
  return {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    server: {
      type: "https",
      options: await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
    },
    port: 3000,
  };
}

When I run this configuration with webpack command webpack --mode development I am getting the expected result of a small transpiled JavaScript file (This is exactly what I need) ...

At the same time, when I run the same configuration with webpack-dev-server to run dev server and host the JavaScript file with the command "webpack-dev-server --mode development I am getting the bundle file which includes dev server dependencies into transpiled JavaScript file ...

How can I get rid of the runtime dependencies to be included with the transpiled JavaScript file? Are there any webpack-dev-server configuration settings that must be added?

See Split Chunks: Example 2

Create a vendors chunk, which includes all code from node_modules in the whole application.

In this way, the ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server, ./node_modules/html-entities and ./node_modules/webpack/hot modules will be splitted from the index.js bundle file.
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
    devServer: {
        static: './dist',
        client: {
            overlay: true,
        },
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

webpack serve logs:
> webpack serve

asset vendors.js 218 KiB [emitted] (name: vendors) (id hint: commons)
asset runtime.js 44.4 KiB [emitted] (name: runtime)
asset index.js 1.4 KiB [emitted] (name: index)
asset index.html 312 bytes [emitted]
Entrypoint index 264 KiB = runtime.js 44.4 KiB vendors.js 218 KiB index.js 1.4 KiB
runtime modules 29.2 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 173 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 69.7 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.3 KiB
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.94 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js 1.86 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 78.9 KiB
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 4.84 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/named-references.js 73.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/numeric-unicode-map.js 389 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/surrogate-pairs.js 583 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
./src/index.js 27 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 312 ms
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8081/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.10.197:8081/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from './dist' directory


Appreciate your time to answer. After all the R&D I've done I have posted the answer to my own question, where your answer is one of the options I have discovered, but unfortunately didn't work for me well.

I would like to provide the answer to my own question and hope it might help someone else. There are 3 different ways I have discovered ...
1. Using optimization
This option was mainly driven by @lin-du answer. His answer is complete and I will not repeat it over there. I just would like to mention that this solution wasn't working for me, but might work for someone else. The main problem in my case was I needed to bundle the dependencies of my project into this single JS file but exclude hot swap and dev-server client dependencies. With these requirements, I would need to "filter out" the vendors I need to include in the bundle file. In this case logic of the test: property will become complex and not future-proof, as I may need to add/remove vendors during future feature development.
2. Using additional parameters for webpack-dev-server
This solution was the answer by @alexander-akait to my question from webpak-dev-server community. He suggested the following: "Without extra code hot and live reloading will not work, anyway you can disable it using client: false and hot: false". The solution was working for my project very well, as the webpack would constantly transpile the TypeScript code according to configuration and the server would serve the actual code change right away. So even with hot reload option turned off my code is constantly refreshing by webpack which is watching my codebase change. Great solution for someone who works with Typescript. I left this solution for my project as an option but ended up using the 3rd solution from the list.
3. Using webpack middleware
This solution completely gives up on webpack-dev-server and uses webpack-dev-middleware as the development tool. I end up using express webserver to serve my content and have all control over this server in the small server.ts file. The solution has not much difference from the option #2, but I like that I won't have any surprises in the future from the webpack-dev-server if any.
